# Regression imputation of missing data

Tags: regression, linear-model, missing-data

Suppose a two-way experiment with interaction. Is it correct to estimate the missing values by OLS, input those values in the data (fill the blanks) and now perform a polynomial (or any kind of) regression? Do you have some literature to suggest about this subject?

Comment: Why is the data missing? Is it random, or is there a underlying pattern?

Comment: Let's consider them MCAR

Comment: See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/StatMatch/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imputation of multiple data sets is better. The approach you suggest would only provide a single data set whose imputed values would be strongly determined by the particular data sample you have. [Multiple imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-imputation/info) (also see [this page](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/MI.html)) stochastically generates a number of separate complete data sets, which are then analyzed separately by the method of interest, like polynomial regression as you suggest. The R package `mice` is one source of the necessary tools, including a wide variety of ways to structure the imputations.